# Export custom module strings for translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've developed some custom modules for a client and implemented the `$this->t()` method to enable translations on static strings, like table headers. Is there a way to export only the translatable strings from my custom module into a .po file that I can handoff to someone for translation? I ideally want to export each modules translations separately so each module can be self contained.

Answer (score 4):

You can give [Translation template extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) a spin. While there is no official release for Drupal 8 available (yet), there already is a development version that seems to work for your use case when using the GUI:

https://www.drupal.org/project/potx/releases

Using composer, just install it like

```
composer require drupal/potx
```

After enabling the module, you'll have a new menu entry *Configuration > Regional and language > User interface translation > Extract* *(/admin/config/regional/translate/extract)*

There you can extract language and module specific translation templates from your custom module's PHP files.

*Disclaimer: As mentioned, this module's Drupal 8 version has not been released yet. It may contain bugs and is not feature complete/en par with the 7.x version. Better use it in your development environment only.*

Comment: Thanks for that I'll give that a try, using it only in a development environment is just fine for our use case.

Comment: @NeilNand I actually tried it in one of our module playgrounds after posting my answer. In my tests it successfully extracted all strings from `$this->t()` and `t()`, and also from class annotations and log messages. The Drush command is not available though. But the back-end forms seem to work just fine.

Comment: This was also what I was looking for. Really great options for extracting translations.